# multi file upload in yii

Tags: yii

I am a newbie in yii framework. I need multiple file upload field in my form like this `http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/widget?view=multifileupload`.

But i could't find the detailed code and upload methods in this url. I also need to save the array of urls of uploaded images in my database. Is there any detailed reference? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Uploading multiple images with CMultiFileUpload look here

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/176/uploading-multiple-images-with-cmultifileupload/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CUploadedFile` to manage files that are being uploaded to your server. To handle multiple just format your model and it's rules correctly, there shouldn't be a problem.

Have a look here to get started:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CUploadedFile
- http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/

Then come back if you've got a specific problem with something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197777/multiple-file-upload-in-yii can you help me to solve same proble