# Multiple file upload in yii

Tags: php, yii

hi i am doing multiple file upload in yii...

i have setup form to use multiple file upload like this...

myfrom.php

```
<?php
$form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'topic-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'), // ADD THIS
));
?>

<div class="row">
<?php
 $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
    'name' => 'imagepath',
    'model'=> $model,
    'attribute'=>'imagepath',
    'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png', // useful for verifying files
    'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', // useful, i think
    'denied' => 'Invalid file type', // useful, i think
));
?>
<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
```

```
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

and my controller method looks like...

```
public function actionMultipleupload() 
{
   $model= new Uploadimage();
    if(isset($_POST['Uploadimage']))
    {
      var_dump("inside if");
    //  $images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('images');
    } 

   var_dump("out side if");
    $this->render('multipleupload',array('model'=>$model));
 }
```

but it's not going inside if loop only if i am using Multiple file upload widget...

it's working fine with single file upload (shown below) and uploading also... but it showing problem in multiple file upload..

```
 <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'imagepath'); ?>
    <?php echo CHtml::activeFileField($model,'imagepath',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>500)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'imagepath'); ?>
 </div>
```

i don't what's going wrong with my code... i am referring this post

Answer (score 0):

Since your are using `attribute` widget option, you should not use `name` :

```
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
    'model'=> $model,
    'attribute'=>'imagepath',
    'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png', // useful for verifying files
    'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', // useful, i think
    'denied' => 'Invalid file type', // useful, i think
));
```

PS: next time you should try a simple `var_dump($_POST);`